# Is the use of two "que" in a row sanctioned by the RAE?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, conjunciones, subordinadas

I just came across this sentence. Notice the two "que" in the beginning:

> *Y es que que la lengua obligue constantemente a escoger palabras y terminaciones que conllevan un género social que no se corresponde con el género de la persona es, como poco, conflictivo.*
>
> <sub>Elena Álvarez Mellado, [*Todas, tod@s, todxs, todes: historia de la disidencia gramatical*](http://www.eldiario.es/zonacritica/Todas-todes-historia-disidencia-gramatical_6_659044117.html).</sub>

A simpler version (more apt as an example for this question) would be:

> *Y es que que la lengua obligue a escoger terminaciones es conflictivo.*

The structure of this sentence has two main parts:

- The main clause. Here, [something] can be a noun, but also a subordinate clause:

  > *"Y es **que*** [something] *es conflictivo"*.
  >   "And it's just **that** [something] is troubling."
- The subordinate clause used to fill [something]:

  > *"**que** la lengua obligue a escoger terminaciones"*
  >   "**that** the language forces you to pick terminations".

The problem (or is it?) is that, when you put them together, you end up with two "que" in a row:

> *"Y es **que que** la lengua obligue a escoger terminaciones es conflictivo"*
>   "And it's just **that that** the language forces you to pick terminations is troubling".

Sure, there're ways to avoid this (mostly the same that in English):

- Drop the *"Y es que"* introduction:

  > *"**Que** la lengua obligue a escoger terminaciones es conflictivo."*
  >   "**That** the language forces you to pick terminations is troubling".
- Introduce an auxiliary noun in between:

  > *"Y es **que** el hecho de **que** la lengua te obligue a escoger terminaciones es conflictivo."*
  >   "And it's just **that** the fact **that** the language forces you to pick terminations is troubling."
- Break the sentence into two conjoined ones:

  > *"Y es **que** la lengua te obliga a escoger terminaciones y eso es conflictivo."*
  >   "And it's just **that** the language forces you to pick terminations and that is troubling."
- Use a comma, maybe (seems a bit forced though):

  > *"Y es **que**, **que** la lengua te obligue a escoger terminaciones, es conflictivo."*
  >   "And it's just **that**, **that** the language forces you to pick terminations, is troubling."

Just fusing the two "que" together seems wrong to me in Spanish, however, since that breaks the subordinate clause:

> Ⓧ *"Y es **que** la lengua te obligue a escoger terminaciones es conflictivo."*
>   "And it's just **that** the language forces you to pick terminations is troubling."

Now, I've come across similar sentences a lot of times, and I had to write them, too. Sometimes I resort to some of the "solutions" above, but some other times I write the two "que" because I don't really think it is grammatically wrong.

So my question is: is using two "que" in a row correct here, where the main sentence already has one "que" introducing a subordinate clause that just happens to start with a second "que"?

Or, to be more specific: **is there any RAE source that states whether this use of two "que" in a row is correct or incorrect?**

<sub>Related: [Two que's in a single sentence](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10687/two-ques-in-a-single-sentence) which asks about using "que" in a weird way to replace a noun, and [Is this a stutter?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13345/is-this-a-stutter) where the second "qué" is quoting a previous question, not introducing a subordinate. These are different cases; also, none of them cite official RAE sources.</sub>

Comment: En el caso de comparaciones, el [DPD en _que_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW) menciona (punto 2.2.2) _es gramaticalmente impecable la emisión conjunta del que comparativo y el que introductor de la subordinada (...) No obstante, para evitar la cacofonía, es habitual introducir entre ambas conjunciones un no expletivo_. Entiendo pues que es correcto pero se aconseja buscar alternativas para evitar el sonido.

Comment: Mi comentario iba en el sentido de que este tipo de cacofonías no parecen estar desaprobadas por la RAE, pero tiende a recomendar que se eviten.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @fedorqui en el sentido de que hay que evitar la cacofonía más allá de que la oración sea gramaticalmente correcta. En el caso que nos ocupa, convertiría la proposición nominal en aposición de "el hecho": *y es que **el hecho de que** la lengua obligue a escoger terminaciones es conflictivo*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buscando en la *Nueva Gramática* se encuentran varios casos de frases que incluyen dos *que* seguidos, y de hecho se explica que no se pueden fusionar (y, en algunos casos, ni siquiera evitar). [Un ejemplo](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bMXFOzgtbyKmhIik):

> Cuando [las construcciones encabezadas por *¿Cómo que...?*] se usan para replicar a un fragmento que contiene una muestra de discurso indirecto, se yuxtaponen dos conjunciones tras el adverbio interrogativo: *—¡Te he dicho que te calles! —¿Cómo que que me calle?* Las dos conjunciones subordinantes no se fusionan aquí en una sola.

Como se ve, no es no diga que esté mal, es que dice que se tiene que escribir así. [Otro ejemplo](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SMzUlOigdlHktmYB):

> Cuando el segundo término de la comparativa de desigualdad es una subordinada sustantiva con verbo en forma personal, aparecen consecutivamente dos conjunciones idénticas: *Es mejor que vayas tú que que vengan ellos*.

Y cita un fragmento de Miguel Delibes:

> Mira, no me calientes la sangre, Facundo, no me calientes la sangre, ya sabes que no hay cosa que más me joda que que me birlen los pájaros que yo mato.

Y es más, [advierte](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SGXUYrpiwXIpaxAl):

> Aunque se registran casos en los que las dos conjunciones se funden en una sola (como en *Es mejor que vayas tú que vengan ellos*), se considera incorrecta esta fusión. Es correcta la concurrencia de la conjunción comparativa ante el relativo *que*, como en *Hay en esa obra mucho más que criticar que que alabar*, a pesar de que el resultado sea poco elegante. Para evitar la concatenación de dos conjunciones idénticas se prefiere a veces insertar la negación expletiva entre ellas [...].

Y cita como ejemplo:

> Yo no sé si he traído mucha comida, pero mira, mejor es que sobre que no que falte.

Con algunos verbos se puede evitar la concurrencia de los dos *que* sustituyendo el primero por *a*:

> Prefiero que estudies más a que salgas tanto por las noches.

Resumiendo: la concurrencia de dos *que* seguidos es perfectamente válida, hasta el punto de que hay casos en los que es necesario escribir las frases así. En todo caso, si se considera que la oración resultante puede ser cacofónica o poco elegante, se puede modificar para obtener un resultado más agradable.